# SQL Join Table A Column A to Table B Column A or B

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

I have 2 tables - A Spend Table and a Sales Table

Spend Table Schema:
Spend_ID,
Spend_amount

Sales Table Schema:
Sales_ID_A,
Sales_ID_B,
Sales_amount

I want to do a left join of the spend table to the sales table. The join key from the spend table is the Spend_ID and i want to join when it matches the value in either Sales_ID_A or Sales_ID_B i.e. my match key on the sales table is in 2 columns. So in a way its like applying an 'or' condition to the join on the sales table Sales_ID_A or Sales_ID_B. If a match is found in Sales_ID_A, then no need to check Sales_ID_B. Only check Sales_ID_B if no match is found in Sales_ID_A. How do i achieve this with SQL?

Sample Data Illustration:

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ChK.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/sample data when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please paste your sample data as text into your request instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns called `sales_id_a` and `sales_id_b` are actually spend IDs and should better be called `spend_id_a` and `spend_id_b`.

You want to join on the first ID, but if that is null, you want to join on the second ID. Use `COALESCE` for this:

```
select *
from sales
left join spend on spend.spend_id = coalesce(sales.sales_id_a, sales.sales_id_b)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However how do we write the query if sales_id_a is a 'non-null' value that does not match, and then we want to therefore check sales_id_b to see if there is a match and therefore do the join based on that? Apologies - i should have been clearer in my original post. but sales_id_a and sales_id_b can include values that are not nulls.  i want to say if sales_id_a matches, join based on that. if not check sales_id_b as the join condition. My understanding is the coalesce function only works if we're dealing with nulls?

Comment: This should never be the case. An ID should have a foreign key to the table it references, so the column can never contain an ID that doesn't exist in the other table. It can only contain a valid ID or null. You may want to reconsider your data model. So yes, `COALESCE` only works with nulls, but this should be all that's necessary in such query.